# Passing Session information in IFRAME

Tags: php, session, iframe

I have an iFRAME that is on a page that is not on the same domain.  I am trying to pass the session id via url.  I set the url such like....

```
 applyonline.php?session_id=3u8ob97d5e3h35povbnuraih22
```

Then I read that session id in with...

```
   $session_id = $_GET['session_id'];
   session_id($session_id);
```

I've tried setting these with no avail...

```
   ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
   ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', '1');
```

I've googled this like crazy and cannot find a solution that works for me.

BTW Firefox works fine because it accepts 3rd party cookies in the iFRAME, IE is the problem.

Comment: I think the answer is yes, but are the two domains are on the same server?  Are you saying in Firefox the method works and you can read the session data, it is just IE that fails?  If each domain runs as a different user, the user of the second domain will most likely not be able to access the session file created by the originating domain.

Comment: Yes it works in Firefox.  The domains are not on the same server.

Comment: Also I'm not passing the information between domains I just need to pass it amongst the iFRAME pages.

Comment: Is the session data stored in a database or memcached server then?

Comment: No it's just stored where the php config has it set to...Sorry not a big help there.

Comment: It's okay, I see what you are trying to do now.  I thought you wanted domain2.com to read session data from domain1.com's session by passing the session ID.  I see now this isn't what you're trying to do.  I'll see if I can think of any other possible solutions.

Comment: I think that this should function outside of the iFRAME for instance if I open the iFRAME URL in Firefox and disable cookies it seems like it should work but I still am not passing via the GET var for some reason.  I was thinking that the session_id($session_id) would set it.

Comment: I was able to accomplish your task (I wasn't testing with iframes though, just deleted my session cookies and restored it manually using the ID from the URL).  I however didn't try to change any of the php settings about use_trans_sid and disable_cookies.  I was able to get it working also with and without changing the session cookie settings.  Since the iframe is the correct domain, I'm not sure why cookies are being a problem.

Comment: I was able to search some more and found that this works... header ( "p3p:CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\""); - Not exactly sure what it is doing but it corrected the issue.

Comment: Excellent, if you mark it as an answer you can accept it and I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `?PHPSESSID=` argument instead.

The cleanest way to do it is described [in the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php):

```
url.php?<?= htmlspecialchars(SID) ?>
```

Comment: So SID is the constant. Is PHPSESSID reserved for storing the session id?

Comment: I tried this by disabling cookies and it still was not working.

Comment: I was able to finally get this working! Your answer did help but if anyone runs into this issue.  You will need to set the session_id($variable) before you start your session with session_start() this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work even though it looks as it is still using cookies:

```
 header ( "p3p:CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```

Comment: there is some explanation what it is http://www.w3.org/TR/P3P11/#compact_policies